# Best way to graphically represent a tree node in Qt

Tags: qt, tree, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to visualise a tree in Qt.

So far, all my nodes consist of simple circles and based on QGraphicsItem class. But I need to display some text over every node, how can I "attach" a QLabel to my nodes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QGraphicsTextItem` on your nodes.

```
QGraphicsTextItem *nodeText = new QGraphicsTextItem("TEXT LABEL", nodeItem);
```

Comment: Yep, I solved my issue by doing what you said. Although I've figured it out by myself, I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you use QTreeView to view your tree ? You *just* have to subclass QAbstractItemModel with your own model and use it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used term "graph" instead of "tree". I'm trying to achieve something like "elastic nodes" example in the Qt demo.